# Auto-populating fields on a form out of the box

Tags: form

Can you auto populate fields on a form out of the box? I'm working on a form and requirements want most of the fields to auto populate. We are not allowed to use anything other than out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Each field has a "Default Value" option. Just set that to whatever you want the initial value to be. It can be overridden by the form user.